# I gat a error due to the influence of migration that I wrote a long time ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add new column 'piece_id' and I added it to Bucket table.

```
class AddPieceIdToBuckets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :buckets, :piece_id, :string
  end
end


class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :piece_id, presence: true
end
```

Also I need to validate piece_id. But Adding validation gives me the following error. I tried run migration without validation and then it passed.

```
undefined method `piece_id'
```

Although I do not have piece_id in migration I wrote in old days, I think that it is the influence that writing validation in the model. And　I created several objects for migration I wrote before. Should I edit it?

```
    def change
        Bucket.reset_column_information
        Bucket.create(
              name: 'test_name',
              about: 'test',
         )
    end
```

Comment: does `piece_id` column present in table ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been bitten by this many times, I no longer put any data changes, via models, in my migrations for this reason.

Since you can be confident that the old migration where you create a Bucket has already run you could remove that bit of code, or better still add `piece_id` to the attributes and give it a value so it passes when migrating from an empty database.

I now use `rake db:seeds` to create data, in `db/seeds.rb` I have:

```
require_relative "seeds/#{Rails.env}/all"
```

and a directory structure such as:

```
db/seeds/development/all.rb
db/seeds/production/all.rb
```

In `development/all.rb` I do `require_relative '../production/all'`.

I run `rake db:seed` as part of deployment, this works well, just have sure that the seeds are idempotent, so check the record does not exist already, or use active record methods like `find_or_create_by`.